# Python ctypes: doesn't load dll as expected

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I am trying to load a library in python in Windows 10 (x64).

The cpp file used to generate the library for testing is:

```
extern "C" int check() {
  return(1);
}
```

Then I generate the dll with the commands (in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt):

```
cl /c mylib.cpp
link /dll /machine:x64 mylib.obj
```

The file mylib.dll is generated.
Then in python, which initializes showing the following string:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
```

I run the following commands:

```
import ctypes
lib=ctypes.CDLL("mylib.dll")
lib.check.restype=(ctypes.c_int,)
```

and the last command fails, saying that doesn't recognize `check`.
I also tried `lib._check` and using a test C file instead of cpp, with the same result, and also tried using `ctypes.WinDLL` instead of `ctypes.CDLL`.

What's wrong? Python is `x64` as well as the library `mylib.dll`...

If I do:

```
ctypes.windll.msvcrt.getchar()
```

the functions works ok… Here I use the MSVCRT library, which is automatically accessible when I load `ctypes`.

Should I compile my library differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your API:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int check() {
  return 1;
}
```

Also `lib.check.restype` should not be a tuple.  `.argtypes` takes a tuple:

```
lib.check.argtypes = ()
lib.check.restype = ctypes.c_int
```

FYI, `cl /LD mylib.cpp` will compile and link a DLL in one step.

Also FYI, `CDLL` and `WinDLL` don't matter on x64, but correspond to `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` calling convention, respectively, on x86.  x64 has only one calling convention so either will work.